# Screenshot utility for Windows with postbox? facility

Tags: windows, images, screenshot

I want to take screenprints and then be able to add a postbox effect to grey out all but a certain area of the screenshot.  I wish I knew where I saw the example of this, they had screenshots in a tutorial and this effect made it all look so clear.  I haven't able to find anything that does the same job.

Any ideas?  Preferably freeware (I'm poor) and compatible with XP to Windows 7.  Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

EDIT - for example, the "lights off" feature on tv.com.  It dims the entire page, apart from the video itself.  It add emphasis and that's effectively what I want to do with screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [free version of FastStone Capture](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html) (in a slightly round-about way)...

1. Take a screenshot
2. Select the area to be highlighted with the Selection Rectangle
3. Invert the selection (Ctrl + Shift + i)
4. 'Ctrl + B' for 'Brightness Contrast Gamma' then reduce the brightness slider
5. 'Ctrl + D' to remove the selection rectangle

If it's a colourful image you can also try 'Effect > Gray Scale' so only the highlighted rectangle is in colour.

[image: Finished screenshot with highlighted paragraph]

Comment: I can see after a little bit of time, this is going to become one of my best friends.  Just what I'm looking for.  Great find, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[ScreenHunter 5.0](http://download.cnet.com/ScreenHunter-Free/3000-2192_4-10063246.html?tag=mncol) is freeware that can screenshoot your entire screen, a selected area, or just the current window with the press of one button.

I don't know what the postbox effect is but I'm sure it is something you could add after the fact if it is necessary.

I like the file naming scheme in ScreenHunter.  It is highly customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has the built in problem step recorder you can use and I highly recommend Snagit.  There are free alternatives that are almost to Snagits ease of use and ability but not there at least in my opinion.

Problem step recorder
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=849

Answer (score 0):

http://greenshot.sourceforge.net/

Opensource, can do selected area, highlight with box, etc. directly copy to the clipboard, open paint editor directly, etc.

I used it everyday, very good program.

Answer (score 0):

Already accepted an answer, but I have to admit that I found something a million times better.

[**Screenshot Captor**](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/)

[image]

After trying nearly every screenshot tool under the sun, I found this to be the most comprehensive tool yet.  It has the ability to grey out all BUT multiple selections of an image.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Definitely worth a look, not just because of the feature set but because the guys behind the software are very active in development of the software, moving it forwards.

I just wish I stumbled on it sooner.